# What does this code, that looks like JavaScript object do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

```
@options = { query: {site: service, page: page} }
```

What does this do? In javascript this, I think would be object definition, however I cannot find what exactly it is in ruby. This would be the full code:

```
class StackExchange
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'api.stackexchange.com'

  def initialize(service, page)
    @options = { query: {site: service, page: page} }
  end

  def questions
    self.class.get("/2.2/questions", @options)
  end

  def users
    self.class.get("/2.2/users", @options)
  end
end
```

Comment: I would like to at least know what this expression is called so I can look up more information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@options = { query: {site: service, page: page} }
```

translates to:

```
@options = {
  :query => {
    :site => service, 
    :page => page
  }
}
```

It was new Hash syntax introduced in 1.9

Comment: Oh, so the tutorials I've looked through did not mention the new syntax available from 1.9. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It's a [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.

Hashes are much like what object literals in javascript are used for.
Originally hashes used a special "hashrocket" syntax exclusively:

```
hash = {
  :a => 1
}
```

Ruby 1.9 introduced an alternate syntax form for when your keys are all [symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html). Which looks a lot like a javascript object literal (which is probably not by accident):

```
hash = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

Unlike Javascript objects Ruby Hashes use only square bracket notation:

```
hash[:a]
```

Answer (score 1):

`@options` is a hash literal with a nested hash. When instantiated the `StackExchange` class needs two arguments, a page and a service.

If you were to call `@options[:query]` it would return the inner hash of `{site­: :serv­ice, page:­ :page­}`. This is simply an organizational way to store different data in a way to help the user understand it.

A few pieces of reading if you are interested:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html - The documents on a ruby hash

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment - this is a good discussion on how different naming conventions come to be.

Answer (score 0):

The code creates a hash ( like in javascript ) and assigns it to the `options` instance value.

```
> options = { query­: {site­: :serv­ice, page:­ :page­} }
=> {:query=>{:site=>:service, :page=>:page}}
> options.cl­ass
=> Hash
```